# Is it possible to start custom glassware using camera button in google glass?

Tags: android, google-glass

The Google glass contains a camera button at the top. By default it invokes the default Google camera app and captures the picture in a single click.

If my app is running, I can receive the camera button pressed event by overriding `onKeyDown()` in my app.

My question is, how can I make the camera button to start my app at first hand?

Also how does the Google camera app gets started when the camera button is pressed and how is the event again passed to `onKeyDown()`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is currently no way for a Glassware other than the built-in Camera to get started when the camera button is pressed on the timeline.

If you would like such a feature, please file a feature request in our [issues tracker](https://code.google.com/p/google-glass-api/issues/list) and explain your use-case so we can properly triage and prioritize.